# Rewrite URL rule for direct/base application only

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

Im looking for a url rewrite to change:

```
/myapplication/  -> www.otherUrl.com
```

However the rest of the files should still work the same

```
/myapplication/default.aspx  -> /myapplication/default.aspx
```

only accessing the base application "/myapplication/" should cause the redirect.

I been trying with

```
      <rule name="Redirect home" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="/myapplication/" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.otherUrl.com" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
```

however this rewrites the entire application to otherurl.

Comment: Can you please attach whole rewrite rule from your web.comfig what you tried?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev I added the entire rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need an exact match:

```
 <match url="^myapplication/?$" />
```

Notice the characters to denote the beginning and end.

The question mark is for the path slash at the end. It makes it optional.

Comment: myapplication/other.aspx seems to be redirecting as well.

Comment: @luisluix: That might be some other rule you have.

Comment: I had them set up as permanent redirects, thats why I wasnt seeing the changes :)

Comment: Ha! That would do it, yes.